# How to make WPF DataGrid scrollbar look like WinForm DataGridView?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

I'm trying to migrate to WPF and evaluating the DataGrid. First, I tried to make the DataGrid look and feel similar to the old DataGridView. The problem is that the scrollbars in DataGrid only cover the scrollable area. That means, the column and row header areas are shown in background color, which looks ugly to me. How can I make the scrollbar to extend to the edge of the control? Is there is property in DataGrid for this?

By the way, did anybody create a style for DataGrid to make it have a similar look and feel of DataGridView (e.g. DataGrid grid line is black by default, Row header doesn't look cool, and it's missing the selection triangle, and the scrollbar problem as described here, and so on)

EDIT: You can [see a screenshot](http://www.goppie.com/tmp/SC_20101001_2329358.png).

Comment: Screen shots would help to illustrate what you mean - I've got an app that exists as both WinForms and WPF and not noticed this before!

Comment: I just tried, but StackOverflow doesn't allow me as a new user to upload images due to spam control. Can I send it to you by email?